# How to swap rows of 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, swap

I am facing this situation for the first time and I would like to know if there is any "best way" or at least a good practice.

How to swap the rows of a 2D array?
For example:

```
FROM   -->   TO
1 1 1        2 2 2
2 2 2        1 1 1
3 3 3        3 3 3
```

- Using `memcpy`?
- Swapping the elements of the two rows one by one thanks to the good old `for`?
- Having an array of dynamically allocated pointers to `int` (instead of the 2D array) and swap the pointers?
- Some other way?

Comment: How do you swap a single integer?  copy to temp, copy to source, copy to dest right?  For performance, if the values are adjecent in memory, like they seem to be above, copying whole roles at a time should be a bit faster.  That said, always measure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using memcpy?

That's probably a good tool to use for this if the data are in row-major order meaning each row is one contiguous block of memory.  A fully general solution would need some upper bound on row size to avoid allocating a gigantic temporary row and thrashing the L1 cache (16 kB might be a reasonable maximum copy chunk size).

> Swapping the elements of the two rows one by one thanks to the good old `for`?

That would be great for small rows or data which for other reasons must be stored in column-major order.

> Having an array of dynamically allocated pointers to int (instead of the 2D array) and swap the pointers?

Certainly worth benchmarking, but unless row swapping is one of your main use cases, this may degrade performance of other operations so much as to be counter-productive.

Here's one more alternative:

Store the data contiguously in row-major order, but rather than moving the rows, keep a separate array of row indexes where each row is really stored.  In your example that would be [1, 0, 2].  This would make row moves efficient like the pointer solution, while not slowing down other operations such as allocation, deallocation, summation, etc.

Comment: Oh that's very clever! Swapping the rows without swapping the rows. It seems to be the easiest and fastest way possible. Thank you for opening my eyes.

Comment: In a very naive benchmark if we really consider swapping rows memcpy wins (result is in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

IMO `memcpy` is the best way
Generic function:

```
void *swapRows(void *array, size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t row1, size_t row2, size_t elemsize)
{
    size_t rowsize = columns * elemsize;
    unsigned char *carray = array;
    if(row1 != row2 && row1 < rows && row2 < rows)
    {
        void *tempRow = malloc(rowsize);
        if(tempRow && array)
        {
            size_t row1offset = row1 * elemsize * columns;
            size_t row2offset = row2 * elemsize * columns;
            memcpy(tempRow, carray + row1offset, rowsize);
            memcpy(carray + row1offset, carray + row2offset, rowsize);
            memcpy(carray + row2offset, tempRow, rowsize);
        }
        free(temprow)
    }
    return array;
}
```

and some primitive benchmark

```
void __attribute__((noinline)) *swapRows(volatile void *array, size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t row1, size_t row2, size_t elemsize)
{
    size_t rowsize = columns * elemsize;
    unsigned char *carray = (void *)array;
    if(row1 != row2 && row1 < rows && row2 < rows)
    {
        void *tempRow = malloc(rowsize);
        if(tempRow && array)
        {
            size_t row1offset = row1 * elemsize * columns;
            size_t row2offset = row2 * elemsize * columns;
            memcpy(tempRow, carray + row1offset, rowsize);
            memcpy(carray + row1offset, carray + row2offset, rowsize);
            memcpy(carray + row2offset, tempRow, rowsize);
        }
        free(tempRow);
    }
    return array;
}

#define SWAPROWS(type, array, rows, columns, r1, r2) \
    do {\
            for(size_t c = 0; c < columns; c++)\
            {   \
                type tmp = array[r1][c];\
                array[r1][c] = array[r2][c];\
                array[r2][c] = tmp; \
            }\
    }while(0)

int main(void)
{
    clock_t start, end;
    volatile int array[5][2000];
    double time_spent;

    for (size_t row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        for(size_t c = 0; c < 2000; c++)
            array[row][c] = row;
    start = clock();    
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        SWAPROWS(int, array, 5, 2000, 2, 3);
    end = clock();  
    time_spent = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
    printf("%f\n", time_spent);
    start = clock();    
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        swapRows(array, 5, 2000, 2, 3, sizeof(int));
    end = clock();  
    time_spent = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
    printf("%f\n", time_spent);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3nc1br

and the result

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout

0.001735
0.000388
```

Comment: I think we found a better approach, but maybe there are cases when we need to actually swap the rows and in those cases we'd better use this nice well-written function.

Comment: I saw the edit with the benchmark. How it comes that swapping two entire arrays of integers is faster than just swapping two integers?

Answer (score 1):

Are we actually wanting to swap in-place or generate a new array with the elements transposed?

If you are trying to swap in-place then is the array square? Now it gets really interesting! I'm ignoring this, but there are some interesting algorithms that can efficiently take a 1-d array that is actually viewed with a second aggregate dimension, and transposes it in-place to the same 1-d array store.

But if you are just doing a square array or copying, then:

If the values are simple integers then memcpy is overkill - you might as well simply assign the values through a temp value. There are no long sequences that memcpy can efficiently stream.

If the elements are larger than integers then making the array be an array of pointers makes the transpose code easy when you just copy the pointers around, but you potentially pay extra everywhere else in your code for managing the data being pointed to, and the extra dereference every time you access the data. The transpose may not be the slowest part of your code!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For *elements larger than integers* do you mean like `long double` or do you mean the case in which the elements are something like arrays?

Comment: When they are any object such as arrays or structs remembering this is C and not C++, you would have to use memcpy at some point anyway, I guess.